# @RestControllerAdvice: Send a response when file is too large

Tags: java, spring-boot

My goal is to receive a message from the API, that tells me that the uploaded image is too large.

I use:

```yaml
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=5MB
server.error.include-message: always
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size: -1
```

From Browser, I send an image file, which is larger than 5 MB. This is my Payload:

[image]

This is how I try to catch an exception and send a response:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({IllegalArgumentException.class, PSQLException.class, ExpiredJwtException.class, MalformedJwtException.class, SignatureException.class, AccessDeniedException.class, MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class, SizeLimitExceededException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception exception) {
        HttpStatus status;
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Caught exception of type: " + exception.getClass().getName());

        switch (exception.getClass().getName()) {
            case "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException", "org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                errorList.add("File should not be larger than 5 MB");
            }
            case "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
                errorList.add("Access Denied");
            }
            // Other exceptions ...
            default -> {
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                errorList.add("An unexpected error occurred.");
                System.out.println("Unhandled exception of type: " + exception.getClass().getName());
            }
        }

        Response response = Response.builder()
                .code(status.name())
                .status(status)
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .messages(errorList)
                .build();

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
    }
}
```

When I debug my code, I see that it goes through the correct statement, and also `response` looks correct. However, in browser (Google Chrome), I don't receive a response.

In the network of my browser, Status is `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

This is my controller:

```java
@PutMapping("/profile-picture")
public ResponseEntity<Response> saveProfilePicture(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
    ResponseData responseData = uploadService.uploadFile(file);
    HttpStatus status = responseData.getStatus();
    String msg = responseData.getMessage();

    Response response = Response.builder()
            .code("PROFILE_PICTURE")
            .status(status)
            .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
            .messages(List.of(msg))
            .build();
    return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
}
```

I catch many other exceptions and they all work fine. This one is special, because the request is a file. How can I fix this?

Comment: although you wrote that you debugged and saw the execution at the right point: where is the `handleExceptions` method called from, as it has visibility `private` ? Maybe you can trace the returned value further after your breakpoint to see what happens to it?

Comment: oh, and please add to your question, what the browser actually receives. Or do you run into a timeout?

Comment: @cyberbrain there is nowhere that I invoke this method. Since I use `@RestControllerAdvice`, this method gets invoked by itself when an exception occurs.

Comment: I didn't mean that _you_ invoke it in your code, but if the method is `private` I'm not sure it get's called properly. Try to make `handleExceptions` `public`.

Comment: @cyberbrain related to browser, I have updated my question. The status is `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`. Also, I have tried it with `public` instead. Still the same issue.

Comment: I built a small example with your code and it worked exactly as you expected it: returns http status 400 with the `Response` as it's created in the exception handler. The difference in the test was: I tested it with my IDEs integrated HTTP request tool, not with a browser (because with a browser I would have to setup an application to send a PUT request). So maybe you try the request with a different tool first and also check for firewalls etc, that could intercept your request.

Comment: @cyberbrain thanks for taking your time to test it, I appreciate that! I found a solution by increasing the value of `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` higher than expected. Then I can validate to see if file is larger than 5 MB. If it is, I will send the status of BAD REQUEST. To avoid unnecessary trafic, I will also validate it in front-end. If it is larger than 5 MB, it will not be sent. Not the best solution, but I can live with that.

Comment: but if it gets larger than the configured multipart.max-file-size then you have the same problem again, right? So I really would recommend to search for the real reason - maybe you have other filters applied?

Comment: @cyberbrain yes, that's correct, then I will have the same problem. I don't see any filters that could effect this issue.